# Failure while implementing a custom validator in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I am trying to implement a custom validator, which checks whether my two new password fields match and throws an error if it doesn't. That's about all the functionality.
I get the following error:

```
Argument of type '{ validator: (formGroup: FormGroup) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'validator' does not exist in type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions'.
```

My code is:

```
profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    currentPassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    newPassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    repeatPassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
  }, {
    validator: ConfirmedValidator('newPassword', 'repeatPassword')
  });
```

Contents of validator.ts:

```
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export function ConfirmedValidator(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string){
return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
        const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
        const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName];
        if (matchingControl.errors && !matchingControl.errors.confirmedValidator) {
            return;
        }
        if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
            matchingControl.setErrors({ confirmedValidator: true });
        } else {
            matchingControl.setErrors(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo: `validator` should be `validators`.

Comment: `Argument of type '{ validators: (formGroup: FormGroup) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions'.
  Types of property 'validators' are incompatible.
    Type '(formGroup: FormGroup) => void' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[]'.
      Type '(formGroup: FormGroup) => void' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
        Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors'.` gets thrown out then.

Comment: A [validator function must return `ValidationErrors` or `null`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn), not `void`. Instead of calling `setErrors()` you must return the errors or `null`.